# Checking sure data doesn't exist in a table in a database before inserting it

Tags: php

I am trying to insert data into a table of three columns using a PHP script. The table named event contains these fields and data

```
  id(int)   event(varchar)                      description (text)
   1        Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit......
```

but before i insert am trying to check if the data doesn't exist before i insert in the table.
Am using the following PHP script to do the checking and inserting but it seems to just be inserting the data even when the data already exists.
What could be the problem and what would be the best way to go about this?

```
   <?php
    $event          = "Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet";
    $description    = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit......";

    if ($check = $db->prepare("SELECT event, description FROM event")) {
        $check->execute();
        $check->bind_result($e, $d);
        $check->fetch();
        $check->close();
     } else {
        echo "SQL Statement could not get executed.";
     }

    if (strcmp($event, $e) && strcmp($description, $d)) {
       echo "Event already exists.";
    } else {
         if ($insert_event = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO event (event, description) VALUES (?,?) ")) {
            $insert_event->bind_param("ss", $event, $description)
            $insert_event->execute();

            $insert_event->close();
          } else {
             echo "SQL Statement could not get executed.";
          }

         header("index.php");
      }

      ?>
```

Comment: First of all `strcmp()` returns 0 when strings are EQUAL. Second why don't you use WHERE to check if some value already exists in the DB?

Comment: Yes, alter your query to:  `SELECT event, description FROM event WHERE event=? AND description=?`, and bind `$event` and `$description` to it. Then when there is 1 or more results, it already exists.